# Unrecognized options "csrf_provider" under "security.firewalls.form_login"

Tags: symfony, csrf, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to install the FOSUserBundle following the tutorial [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#step-4-configure-your-applications-securityyml)

When I'm at the 7th step I try to update the database schema for ORM running

*php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force*

but appears the error

```
InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized options "csrf_provider" under "security.firewalls.form_login"
```

Here's my firewall:

```
firewalls:
        main:
        pattern: 
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
```

What can I do? I don't set a pattern because, if I set something like

```
        pattern: ^/
```

the following error appears:

InvalidTypeException: Invalid type for path "security.firewalls.pattern". Expected array, but got string

UPDATE:

The csrf_protection was enable but, for some reason that I don't understand, didn't work. I tried to "reset" it, disabling and enabling, and now it works.
In my project I enable it with

```
csrf_protection: ~
```

Comment: There has been a change in the meantime. The options name has changed from csrf_provider --> csrf_token_generator http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353510/symfony2-logout-csrf-protection-csrf-provider-unrecognized

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to enable csrf protection.
You can do that by adding a key to the config.yml

```
framework:
    csrf_protection:
        enabled: true
```

Answer (score 2):

in security.yml

for sloving this problem you just need to comment this command :

csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

and enable this comment instead :

csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

Answer (score 0):

There can be 3 main reasons for this problem:

1. You have configured FOSU from cookbook from symfony.com, which now is outdated for FOSU 2.0+. Solution:

`csrf_token_generator` Instead of
    `csrf_provider`

```
in security.yml
```

2. You have not enabled csrf in config.yml

   `framework:
   csrf_protection:
       enabled: true`
3. You didn't update AppKernel.php with:

   `new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),`

   Maybe all at once. Good luck :)