# Symfony2 logout CSRF protection: csrf_provider unrecognized

Tags: symfony, logout, csrf-protection

How can I protect the logout action? I read [default configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/2.4/reference/configuration/security.html), and set

```
logout:
    csrf_parameter:       _token
    csrf_provider:        ~
    intention:            logout
```

but when I'm trying to clear cache the following error displayed:

> [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
>   Unrecognized options "csrf_provider" under "security.firewalls.main.logout"

I'm using Symfony 2.4 + FOSUserBundle 1.3.

Comment: Could you rephrase your question title? Usually it should **not contain any** key words tagged in the question. Your title consists only of the keywords.

Comment: Have you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350330/unrecognized-options-csrf-provider-under-security-firewalls-form-login ?

Comment: @isi sorry, but I can't rephrase it, because it is very specific one and my imagination and low English skills prevents do this :( If moderators consider it necessary to rephrase it - I agree.

Comment: @DenisV I have already checked this topic. It isn't too related to my question, but CSRF protection is already enabled in my app.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've researched the Symfony's code and find that now `csrf_provider` option renamed to `csrf_token_generator`. Then I googled and found related [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/9176). So the problem in an unsynchronized documentation.

The final solution is:

**configuration:**

```
# app/config/security.yml

security:
    # ...
    firewalls:
        # ...
        your_firewall_name:
            # ...
            logout:
                # ...
                csrf_token_generator: your_csrf_provider # e.g. form.csrf_provider
```

**twig template:**

```
<a href="{{ logout_url('your_firewall_name') }}">Logout</a>
```

Note, that we're using `logout_url()` instead of `logout_path()` due to helper bug (it generates absolute path without `app_dev.php` suffix in dev environment). Theese twig helpers appends `%token_parameter%` to your logout URI, e.g. `http://example.com/app_dev.php/logout?_csrf_token=36wX6HYU2ASeZBQw_iwKcUDbplmFm4W7Ez-tMaavDNo`.

Hope this information will be helpful.